To check two lists for differences, should I use LINQ or ForEach?
I was stout enough to think that I understood the underlying question of the original OP. Here is my edited interpretation. Shoot me if I'm stepping out of line ;)
I display a collection of objects. The operator can edit this collection. He can add elements, he can remove elements, and he can change elements. After editing, the operator presses a button to indicate that he has finished editing.
My program needs to process the edited list.
For this I have the original sequence of elements, and the edited sequence of elements. My program needs to find out which elements are removed, which are added, and which are changed.
So I have something like this:
class Element {...}

IEnumerable<Element> originalElements = ...
IEnumerable<Element> editedElements = ...

I need to make three sequences:
IEnumerable<Element> addedElements = ...
IEnumerable<Element> removedElements = ...
IEnumerable<Element> changedElements = ...

For this I could use LINQ, probably something with Except. I could also enumerate the sequences to create the desired collections.
Question: which method is preferable?
Original Question that was closed due to lack of information:
requestList = ["elem1", "elem2", "elem3"];
existList = ["elem1", "elem4", "elem5"];

Need to get like this
needToAddList = ["elem2", "elem3"];
needToRemoveList = ["elem4", "elem5"];
noChanges = ["elem1"];

Foreach loop or LINQ (except & intersect)
which is best for this type of filter?

Which aspect is best referred to?

'best' is subjective - are you talking about performance, readability, or something else? If the functionality is offered in linq then use that, if you prefer to use foreach if it makes your intent clearer then use that. If you're concerned about performance then test both to see which is best for you.

Except and Intersect will likely be much faster for large lists than an On^2 nested loops approach, but they will automatically dedupe. Is this a problem?

Is that actually List<string> or something else? What's "most efficient" (which I guess you mean by 'best') may depend heavily on the actual collection type. And also - if you can - the expected average size of the lists is important. Also the size relation: is existing and requested going to be about the same sizes, will they differ vastly? Are additions going to happen in "many at once" fashion but removals in "low number but more often" ... ?

For HashSets and not too many entries, you could do smth like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hNo6fg

@Harald, I'm not a domain expert but this edit looks very heavy-handed. You've added a ton of information and context that may or may not reflect the original question. But that's almost beside the point since the edited question is still off-topic as primiarily opinion-based and should remain closed.

Why not use the List<>.Where(), List<>.AddRange() and Array.ToList() to add filtered items to the other lists
noChange.AddRange(requestList.Where(item => existList.Contains(item)).ToList());
needToAddList.AddRange(requestList.Where(item => existList.Contains(item)).ToList());
needToRemoveList.AddRange(existList.Where(item => !requestList.Contains(item)).ToList());

Make sure you clear the lists when you do this again (Like when you use it in a function)
    List<string> requestList = ["elem1", "elem2", "elem3"];
    List<string> existList = ["elem1", "elem4", "elem5"];

    List<string> noChange = new List<string>();
    List<string> needToAddList = new List<string>();
    List<string> needToRemoveList = new List<string>();

    private void FilterLists()
    {
        noChange.Clear();
        needToAddList.Clear();
        needToRemoveList.Clear();
        noChange.AddRange(requestList.Where(item => existList.Contains(item)).ToList());
        needToAddList.AddRange(requestList.Where(item => !existList.Contains(item)).ToList());
        needToRemoveList.AddRange(existList.Where(item => !requestList.Contains(item)).ToList());
    }

Edit:
Using Intersect and Except you can use almost the same basis
noChange.AddRange(existList.Intersect(requestList).ToList());
needToAddList.AddRange(requestList.Except(existList).ToList());
needToRemoveList.AddRange(existList.Except(requestList).ToList());

Or use string[] maybe, i'm not that experienced with massive lists and performance of these...
string[] noChange = existList.Intersect(requestList).ToArray()
string[] needToAddList = requestList.Except(existList).ToArray()
string[] needToRemoveList = existList.Except(requestList).ToArray()


Because you don't know much about the sizes of the lists at this stage of the question maturity; this approach would potentially have relatively horrendous performance on large lists. Also, there is no need for global state for this operation, and if concurrent filtering were required, it could easily give unpredictable results/fail

You can use LINQ to output a collection of items where each list has the same item:
string[] noChanges = needToAddList
    .Where(a1 => needToRemoveList
        .Any(a2 => a1.Contains(a2))
    )
.ToArray();

